# Unexpected logcat errors when running android camerax without an ImageCapture use case

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-camerax

Finished going through the [codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started/#5) tutorial and everything is working just fine, but after removing the ImageCapture use case, I get a reoccurring error in the logcat every 50 ms or so.

Here are three lines of said error:

```
07-28 18:22:16.225 211-29468/? E/mm-camera: module_faceproc_port_event_func:886] MCT_EVENT_MODULE_BUF_DIVERT 65539, Cannot start FD, active 10002, frameid 432 431, native 1, mapped 1 1
07-28 18:22:16.258 211-29468/? E/mm-camera: module_faceproc_port_event_func:886] MCT_EVENT_MODULE_BUF_DIVERT 65539, Cannot start FD, active 10002, frameid 433 432, native 1, mapped 1 1
07-28 18:22:16.291 211-29468/? E/mm-camera: module_faceproc_port_event_func:886] MCT_EVENT_MODULE_BUF_DIVERT 65539, Cannot start FD, active 10002, frameid 434 433, native 1, mapped 1 1
```

I had this same error when trying to implement an ImageAnalysis use case via the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/analyze) as well, in which I also did not include an ImageCapture use case. Is there some inherent requirement to also create an ImageCapture use case that I am missing in the docs?

Where is mm-camera tagged error log coming from? I'm not easily finding anything in the code, docs, or Google to tell me what this mm-camera is.

Code for both cases below. I've added ////////////////////////////////// bars to highlight the two small differences.

#### Working CodeLabs Final Code:

```kotlin
package jp.oist.cameraxapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.net.Uri
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import androidx.camera.core.*
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.io.File
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
typealias LumaListener = (luma: Double) -> Unit

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var preview: Preview? = null
    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null
    private var imageAnalyzer: ImageAnalysis? = null
    private var camera: Camera? = null

    private lateinit var outputDirectory: File
    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Request camera permissions
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            startCamera()
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS)
        }

        // Setup the listener for take photo button
        camera_capture_button.setOnClickListener { takePhoto() }

        outputDirectory = getOutputDirectory()

        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    }

    private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
            // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            // Preview
            preview = Preview.Builder()
                    .build()

            imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
                    .build()

            imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                    .build()
                    .also {
                        it.setAnalyzer(cameraExecutor, LuminosityAnalyzer { luma ->
                            Log.d(TAG, "Average luminosity: $luma")
                        })
                    }

            // Select back camera
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK).build()

            try {
                // Unbind use cases before rebinding
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                // Bind use cases to camera
                camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                        this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture, imageAnalyzer)
                preview?.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.createSurfaceProvider(camera?.cameraInfo))
            } catch(exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }

        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

    private fun takePhoto() {
        // Get a stable reference of the modifiable image capture use case
        val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return

        // Create timestamped output file to hold the image
        val photoFile = File(
                outputDirectory,
                SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.US
                ).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg")

        // Create output options object which contains file + metadata
        val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()

        // Setup image capture listener which is triggered after photo has
        // been taken
        imageCapture.takePicture(
                outputOptions, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
            override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exc.message}", exc)
            }

            override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                val savedUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile)
                val msg = "Photo capture succeeded: $savedUri"
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.d(TAG, msg)
            }
        })
    }
    private fun allPermissionsGranted() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                baseContext, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    fun getOutputDirectory(): File {
        val mediaDir = externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull()?.let {
            File(it, resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply { mkdirs() } }
        return if (mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists())
            mediaDir else filesDir
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "CameraXBasic"
        private const val FILENAME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS"
        private const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10
        private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
            requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults:
            IntArray) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS) {
            if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
                startCamera()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Permissions not granted by the user.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                finish()
            }
        }
    }

    private class LuminosityAnalyzer(private val listener: LumaListener) : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

        private fun ByteBuffer.toByteArray(): ByteArray {
            rewind()    // Rewind the buffer to zero
            val data = ByteArray(remaining())
            get(data)   // Copy the buffer into a byte array
            return data // Return the byte array
        }

        override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy) {

            val buffer = image.planes[0].buffer
            val data = buffer.toByteArray()
            val pixels = data.map { it.toInt() and 0xFF }
            val luma = pixels.average()

            listener(luma)

            image.close()
        }
    }
}
```

#### Edited Code to remove the ImageCapture use case:

```kotlin
package jp.oist.cameraxapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.net.Uri
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import androidx.camera.core.*
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.io.File
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
typealias LumaListener = (luma: Double) -> Unit

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var preview: Preview? = null
    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null
    private var imageAnalyzer: ImageAnalysis? = null
    private var camera: Camera? = null

    private lateinit var outputDirectory: File
    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Request camera permissions
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            startCamera()
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS)
        }

        // Setup the listener for take photo button
        camera_capture_button.setOnClickListener { takePhoto() }

        outputDirectory = getOutputDirectory()

        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    }

    private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
            // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            // Preview
            preview = Preview.Builder()
                    .build()

            ////////////////////////////////////////// Removed imageCapture object

            imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                    .build()
                    .also {
                        it.setAnalyzer(cameraExecutor, LuminosityAnalyzer { luma ->
                            Log.d(TAG, "Average luminosity: $luma")
                        })
                    }

            // Select back camera
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK).build()

            try {
                // Unbind use cases before rebinding
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                // Bind use cases to camera
                ////////////////////////////////////////// Removed imageCapture from bindToLifecycle
                camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                        this, cameraSelector, preview, imageAnalyzer)
                preview?.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.createSurfaceProvider(camera?.cameraInfo))
            } catch(exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }

        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

    private fun takePhoto() {
        // Get a stable reference of the modifiable image capture use case
        val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return

        // Create timestamped output file to hold the image
        val photoFile = File(
                outputDirectory,
                SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.US
                ).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg")

        // Create output options object which contains file + metadata
        val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()

        // Setup image capture listener which is triggered after photo has
        // been taken
        imageCapture.takePicture(
                outputOptions, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
            override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exc.message}", exc)
            }

            override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                val savedUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile)
                val msg = "Photo capture succeeded: $savedUri"
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.d(TAG, msg)
            }
        })
    }
    private fun allPermissionsGranted() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                baseContext, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    fun getOutputDirectory(): File {
        val mediaDir = externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull()?.let {
            File(it, resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply { mkdirs() } }
        return if (mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists())
            mediaDir else filesDir
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "CameraXBasic"
        private const val FILENAME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS"
        private const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10
        private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
            requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults:
            IntArray) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS) {
            if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
                startCamera()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Permissions not granted by the user.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                finish()
            }
        }
    }

    private class LuminosityAnalyzer(private val listener: LumaListener) : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

        private fun ByteBuffer.toByteArray(): ByteArray {
            rewind()    // Rewind the buffer to zero
            val data = ByteArray(remaining())
            get(data)   // Copy the buffer into a byte array
            return data // Return the byte array
        }

        override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy) {

            val buffer = image.planes[0].buffer
            val data = buffer.toByteArray()
            val pixels = data.map { it.toInt() and 0xFF }
            val luma = pixels.average()

            listener(luma)

            image.close()
        }
    }
}
```

#### Build and Phone Details:

Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1

Android Studio 4.0
Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223, built on May 21, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 5.3.0-46-generic
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1981M
Cores: 8
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: PlantUML integration, SequenceDiagram, org.jetbrains.kotlin, com.google.services.firebase, com.intellij.marketplace, com.thoughtworks.gauge, org.intellij.plugins.markdown, org.pmesmeur.sketchit, ru.leoklo.stackuml, simpleUML

### Edit1 (Adding Java example code exhibiting same behavior):

I wanted to add another example that results in the same logcat errors. Following the example code snippets and filling in the gaps from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax), one can arrive at the following code when finishing up the [Preview](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/preview) section of the docs, with a working Preview use case:

```
package jp.oist.cameraxapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.camera.core.Camera;
import androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector;
import androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis;
import androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture;
import androidx.camera.core.ImageProxy;
import androidx.camera.core.Preview;
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider;
import androidx.camera.view.PreviewView;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Size;

import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageCapture imageCapture;
    private ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture;
//    private ExecutorService executor;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        PreviewView previewView = findViewById(R.id.previewView);

        cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(() -> {
            try {
                // Camera provider is now guaranteed to be available
                ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();

                // Set up the view finder use case to display camera preview
                Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();

                // Choose the camera by requiring a lens facing
                CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                        .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT)
                        .build();

                // Connect the preview use case to the previewView
                preview.setSurfaceProvider(
                        previewView.createSurfaceProvider());

                // Set up the capture use case to allow users to take photos
//                imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder()
//                        .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
//                        .build();

//                ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis =
//                        new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
//                                .setTargetResolution(new Size(1280, 720))
//                                .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
//                                .build();
//
//                imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(executor, new ImageAnalysis.Analyzer() {
//                    @Override
//                    public void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy image) {
//                        int rotationDegrees = image.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees();
//                        Log.i("CameraXApp3", "Image Analyzed");
//                    }
//                });

                // Attach use cases to the camera with the same lifecycle owner
                Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                        ((LifecycleOwner) this),
                        cameraSelector,
                        preview);

            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                // Currently no exceptions thrown. cameraProviderFuture.get() should
                // not block since the listener is being called, so no need to
                // handle InterruptedException.
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));
    }

}
```

This works fine, and no logcat errors. I'll add the manifest and layout XML at the end as it is identical, but compare this code with that below, which just uncommments a few lines to add an empty ImageAnalyzer, and required executor to the mix:

```
package jp.oist.cameraxapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.camera.core.Camera;
import androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector;
import androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis;
import androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture;
import androidx.camera.core.ImageProxy;
import androidx.camera.core.Preview;
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider;
import androidx.camera.view.PreviewView;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Size;

import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageCapture imageCapture;
    private ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture;
    private ExecutorService executor;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        PreviewView previewView = findViewById(R.id.previewView);

        cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(() -> {
            try {
                // Camera provider is now guaranteed to be available
                ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();

                // Set up the view finder use case to display camera preview
                Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();

                // Choose the camera by requiring a lens facing
                CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                        .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT)
                        .build();

                // Connect the preview use case to the previewView
                preview.setSurfaceProvider(
                        previewView.createSurfaceProvider());

                // Set up the capture use case to allow users to take photos
//                imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder()
//                        .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
//                        .build();

                ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis =
                        new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                                .setTargetResolution(new Size(1280, 720))
                                .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                                .build();

                imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(executor, new ImageAnalysis.Analyzer() {
                    @Override
                    public void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy image) {
                        int rotationDegrees = image.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees();
                        Log.i("CameraXApp3", "Image Analyzed");
                    }
                });

                // Attach use cases to the camera with the same lifecycle owner
                Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                        ((LifecycleOwner) this),
                        cameraSelector,
                        preview,
                        imageAnalysis);

            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                // Currently no exceptions thrown. cameraProviderFuture.get() should
                // not block since the listener is being called, so no need to
                // handle InterruptedException.
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));
    }

}
```

This produces the same logcat errors as seen in the codelabs example code:

```
07-28 18:22:16.225 211-29468/? E/mm-camera: module_faceproc_port_event_func:886] MCT_EVENT_MODULE_BUF_DIVERT 65539, Cannot start FD, active 10002, frameid 432 431, native 1, mapped 1 1
07-28 18:22:16.258 211-29468/? E/mm-camera: module_faceproc_port_event_func:886] MCT_EVENT_MODULE_BUF_DIVERT 65539, Cannot start FD, active 10002, frameid 433 432, native 1, mapped 1 1
07-28 18:22:16.291 211-29468/? E/mm-camera: module_faceproc_port_event_func:886] MCT_EVENT_MODULE_BUF_DIVERT 65539, Cannot start FD, active 10002, frameid 434 433, native 1, mapped 1 1
```

It appears the creation of the imageAnalysis object does not create this itself, since I can leave this code as is, but just remove the imageAnalysis object from the bindToLifecycle() call, and this error disappears. My guess is that I've set something up wrong between the executor tied to the imageAnalysis object and the lifecycle of the cameraProvider. I'm fairly new to both concepts, so my ignorance in this area is the only reason I suspect this to the issue (as I don't properly understand it). Is there some obvious no-no that I can commited here?

Layout XML and Manifest below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
            android:id="@+id/previewView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    </FrameLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="jp.oist.cameraxapp">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

## TLDR

Looks like a bug or limited capability related to any mlkit package <16.2.0. Update any mlkit implementations in your app-level gradle file to those above 16.2.0 (though these versions are not yet available for several of the packages):

```
    // implementation 'com.google.mlkit:object-detection:16.1.0'
    // implementation 'com.google.mlkit:object-detection:16.2.0'
```

## Exhaustive Explanation

Updating the `com.google.mlkit:object-detection:16.1.0` package to `com.google.mlkit:object-detection:16.2.0` in my app level gradle file makes the error reliably disappear.

### Highlighting Code in Question:

```
// ------------------Error Start------------------ 
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:object-detection:16.2.0'
// ------------------Error End------------------
```

### Full Error Producing Gradle File

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "jp.oist.cameraxapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.0-beta07'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    // CameraX core library using the camera2 implementation
    def camerax_version = "1.0.0-beta07"
    // The following line is optional, as the core library is included indirectly by camera-camera2
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
    // If you want to additionally use the CameraX Lifecycle library
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${camerax_version}"
    // If you want to additionally use the CameraX View class
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha14"
    // If you want to additionally use the CameraX Extensions library
//    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.0.0-alpha14"
// ------------------Error Start------------------ 
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:object-detection:16.1.0'
// ------------------Error End------------------ 
//    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:face-detection:16.0.1'
//    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:16.0.1'


}
```

### Full Error Free Gradle File

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "jp.oist.cameraxapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.0-beta07'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    // CameraX core library using the camera2 implementation
    def camerax_version = "1.0.0-beta07"
    // The following line is optional, as the core library is included indirectly by camera-camera2
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
    // If you want to additionally use the CameraX Lifecycle library
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${camerax_version}"
    // If you want to additionally use the CameraX View class
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha14"
    // If you want to additionally use the CameraX Extensions library
//    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.0.0-alpha14"
// ------------------Error Start------------------ 
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:object-detection:16.2.0'
// ------------------Error End------------------ 
//    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:face-detection:16.0.1'
//    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:16.0.1'


}
```

What is surprising is that I have no direct dependencies on any mlkit package in my MainActivity.java file, and no other java files in the project. The implementations were simply there in order to use them later in the ImageAnalysis section of the code, which were not yet implemented.

This might have something to do with the custom executors mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/release-notes).

> On Android, added support for specifying your own custom Executor for running expensive tasks like model loading and inference to Image Labeling and Object Detection and Tracking. With this release, all ML Kit APIs now support custom executors.

> By default, ML Kit uses a highly optimized, internally managed thread pool to run background tasks. This API can help with specialized use cases where developers want to keep full control over the threads in their app instead.

as I was using such an executor, but I'm not sure how to use the "internally managed thread pool" mentioned. Also, as I have no direct dependencies on any mlkit package in the current code, I'm at a loss for how the mlkit packages were generating these logcat errors in the first place, but there you have it. Please add a better answer, or comments to provide insight if you have any!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some inherent requirement to also create an ImageCapture use
> case that I am missing in the docs?

No, there isn't. You can use preview and image analysis on their own without and image capture use case. You can check out the supported use case combinations in the table at the end of [this section](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/architecture#combine-use-cases) from the documentation.

> Where is mm-camera tagged error log coming from?

It is not a CameraX log, it is most likely a log from the camera framework/HAL. You can find references to it in [code search](https://cs.android.com/search?q=mm-camera&sq=&ss=android).

Comment: Yeah, I read through those docs, including the referenced table. I also used the example code for the combined use case in the link you mentioned. This code produced the same error in the logcats. If I add an ImageCapture object and tie to the lifecycle, these errors disappear. I thought this was something I was doing wrong somehow, but when I saw the same error appear when running through the codelabs code, I thought it was worth asking here.

Comment: I've added a new section to the question which uses an example code from the Android Docs directly (rather than codelabs). This example is in Java and exhibits the same logcat errors.